# Extension: Provide code navigation support for custom script language

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to support basic code navigation in my extension for my custom script langauge. Things are not too complicated, a simple regex can actually find where a call or jump occurs and where it goes. VSCode API says: (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)

> Despite that, features like automatic word-completion, **code navigation**, or code checking have become popular across different tools for different programming languages.

So I think it should be possible, but I can't find any API for that. I don't yet want to implement a full-blown external language server, but the simpler in-built typescript.

*I might misuse the term "code navigation", so under that I mean that if I ctrl+click a variable or function name I can navigate where it is declared.*

Is there any API for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDefinitionProvider).

> The definition provider interface defines the contract between extensions and the go to definition and peek definition features.

Relevant section of the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-definitions-of-a-symbol).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :)